# How to convert a date from format MM/dd/yyyy to Julian format CCYYDDD?

Tags: c#-3.0

I have the following function "Format" to convert a date from the format "MM/dd/yyyy" to MMddyyyy.
This function works with the below data but would not work if I want to convert a date from "MM/dd/yyyy" to CCYYDDD. What should be done in this function to support Julian date conversion? Thanks for any help!

```
string Value = "03/11/2011";
string formatType = "System.DateTime";
string outputformat = "MMddyyyy";

Value = Format(formatType, Value, outputformat);

private static string Format(string typename, string value, string format)
    {
        Type t = Type.GetType(typename);

        System.Reflection.MethodInfo infoParse = t.GetMethod("Parse", new Type[] { typeof(string) });
        object o = infoParse.Invoke(null, new object[] { value });

        System.Reflection.MethodInfo infoToString = t.GetMethod("ToString", new Type[] { typeof(string) });

        return infoToString.Invoke(o, new object[] { format }) as string;
    }
```

Comment: Why the reflection code?  Can't you just use DateTime objects directly?

Comment: The same function is used for other conversions too so we are using reflection.

Comment: My suggestion would be to handle the different types independently rather than trying to generalize using reflection.  The DateTime has other useful methods such as ParseExact and also it has the DayOfYear property which will give you the DDD part you need.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It looks like it is not possible to use the same function for Julian dates.

Answer (score -1):

Use the output format "yyyyddd".